# Get strings from Android xml in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I need to write a php script that reads a xml android string file, search for string names and return the value of the string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string1">First String</string>
    <string name="string2">Second String</string>
    <string name="string3">Third String</string>
</resources>
```

I just need a simple function `get_string($name)` that accepts "string1" as parameter and returns "First String". Either **DOM** or **SimpleXML** would be ok.

Comment: I haven't found any example on the internet. Tried to loop the attributes array but with no luck. (only can get attr[0] attr[1] etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to did it! The key was to cycle the array and get the value at selected index. If anyone has a better solution, feel free to post it.

```
function xml_attribute($doc, $attribute)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($doc->string as $string)
    {
        if($string['name'] == $attribute) {
        return $doc->string[$i];
    }   
    $i++;

    }
}
```